# SQL Primary Key/Table Joining

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

Alright, this is a relativly simple question that I just need confirmation on. I am pretty sure I know the answer, but I need expert validation because I have OCD.

Anyways, I am wondering what the difference is between just a simple Inner Join Statement
and simply using the where clause to set the primary keys of the tables I am matching as = to each other.

Example: I wrote this

```
select a.CONTACT_ID, a.TRADE_REP as Rep_Trading_ID, p.CRD_NUMBER, c.FIRST_NAME, c.LAST_NAME
from dbo.REP_PROFILE p, dbo.REP_ALIAS a, dbo.CONTACT c
where 
c.CONTACT_ID = p.CONTACT_ID
and p.CONTACT_ID = a.TRADE_REP 
and a.PRIMARY_YN = 'y'
```

In my mind, this seems to perform the exact same query as if I were to have created and Inner Join between tables c and p and another inner join between tables p and a on Contact ID (Contact ID is my primary key for most everything)

Am I correct? Am I partially correct? Am I tottally hopelessly ignorant? Any validation will do

Comment: possible duplicate of [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the same!

look at these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(20)
);
```

The execution plan for the query using the inner join:

```
-- with inner join

EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;

SELECT *
FROM TABLE (DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);

-- 0 select statement
-- 1 hash join (access("T1"."ID"="T2"."ID"))
-- 2 table access full table1
-- 3 table access full table2
```

And the execution plan for the query using a WHERE clause.

```
-- with where clause

EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT * FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id;

SELECT *
FROM TABLE (DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);

-- 0 select statement
-- 1 hash join (access("T1"."ID"="T2"."ID"))
-- 2 table access full table1
-- 3 table access full table2
```

In my opinion is more readable to use JOIN.

Comment: I agree on the readability, and I prefer to use JOIN statements as it seems more politically correct. I was just wondering if the underlying action being performed was identical, and you sir have showed me exactly what I was looking for, Thanks!

Comment: @AdamW: Yes, it is. I was wrong by putting `EXPLAIN` in the answer because it is for MySQL. But always you have a doubt about how a query is executed in SQL Server, you should use "Display Estimated Execution Plan" in SQL Server Management Studio. That way you could see if it has a lack of indexes or if it is a wrong query. Is the best way to optimize a query. However, the answer is still the same,  `JOIN` (not `LEFT JOIN` or any other variance) and `WHERE` works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the format you provided works fine for INNER JOINS.

But what to do when you get to LEFT/RIGHT JOINS? Then you cannot use the joining conditions in the where clause like that.

Now if I am not mistaken, the old school syntax would be somethine like

```
=* for LEFT JOIN
```

and

```
*= for RIGHT JOIN
```

You might wfind the following article a nice read (more specifically at the various JOIN types)

[Join (SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

Comment: Thank you for the response! I alsways love learning little bits of forgotten syntax. When using other joins I like to use a Printout of Visual SQL joins, which can be found here http://www.j0zf.com/uploads/dynamic_areas/lP2fs2414xx6pXdIbGir/1/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Doing `JOIN` syntax is much easier to read (everything is obvious where it goes and things like that).  It is also considered more flexible since changing `JOIN` to `OUTER JOIN` is extremely easy and much more maleable.

See this post for much more detail (it is MySQL, but the same issues arise/apply): [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)